# Python Selenium webscraping no available login element. Pause script for manual login

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make a tool to pull data from a website but the initial login page has no elements when I go to inspect it (Ctrl + Shift + I).

I'm already logged into the website, however, webdriver opens a new Chrome window to the login page.
Ideally I'd like to skip this and automatically login but that doesn't seem possible with no element id or anything to point to for username/pass.

So (unless anyone has a better idea), how can I pause my code until the user has successfully and manually logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add explicitly wait on the element located after login step:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


timeout = 300
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(your_url)

myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "xpath of the element after login step")))
```

so, it will wait until you login or 300 seconds. If you login earlier it will continue instantly

but, better to automate login step as well

Comment: I believe that worked! To be clear, I added the XPATH of an element (search box) that is only visible once the user is past the login screen. This is how your above code is intended, correct?

Comment: @Retsied yes, the code will wait only element after login, f.i search

Comment: @Retsied you can also save cookies to the file after login. And paste them to future driver. To skip login step